# Terminate system() function in c++

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm writing a c++ function that uses the system() function to use the windows cmd. Some of the commands I need to use don't exit automatically and need to be exited via other means. Using Control+C works with these, but that doesn't work as a system() function. I've messed around with this for a few hours today and I'm still no closer to solving it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use a process launching API that offers more control, e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/process.html

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Linux Programmer's Manual for system() call:

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3) as follows:

```
      execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
```

> system() returns after the command has been completed.

If you wan't to use commands that don't return you should consider using
fork() and exec() calls in-order not to block the main thread (as will happen when using system() call).

Comment: On Windows (which OP seems to be using), fork() and exec() are not readily available without a translation layer like cygwin.